# How to delete many to many relationship (python3 flask SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python-3.x, object, flask, sqlalchemy

How is it you delete a many to many relationship between 2 objects?
exapmle:
A user follows a channell and wants to unfollow the channel

Comment: How you're running those functions?

Comment: Still not clear how you're running those functions and the question itself it's unclear. Please take some time to edit your question so that we can understand your situation better.